# How to get model from sequelize.model after use sequelize-cli

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I use sequelize-cli to auto generate code for model Student:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var _stu = sequelize.define('stu', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return _stu
};
```

My question are

1. How to get model  named `stu`? As the `sequelize` is defined in function signature.

When `sequelize model:generate`,sequelize read config in config.json,where dbname,passowrd are specified.

2. How the `sequelize` in the function signature knows database connection config,say,name,password,etc as I don't specify in this js file.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for question 1:
*"sequelize.import"* will do this job.

Try this code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...)

const stu = sequelize.import('./models/stu')

stu.findAll.then(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you generate models via the CLI, it creates a handy `models/index.js` file that handles passing in a `Sequelize` instance for you. You can simply require cherry picked, existing models via ES6 destructuring like this:

```
var { stu } = require("./models");

stu.findAll().then(...);
```

Alternatively, you could require them all at once, and then access specific models as needed:

```
var models = require("./models");

models.stu.findAll().then(...);
```

Comment: Thanks it really helped me. I was trying to fetch the model directly.

Answer (score 0):

The way i make it works was importing model with the `require()` function and then call it with required parameters.

## Explanation

By require function you will get another function that returns your model.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const stu = sequelize.define('stu', {
    // ...database fields
  }, {});
  stu.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return sty;
} // note that module.exports is a function
```

Now, this function requires the initialized `sequelize` object and a `DataTypes object`, so you just have to pass the instance of `sequelize` and `Sequelize.DataTypes` and then it will return your model, example:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);

const Stu = require('./models/stu')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

Finally you can get your database rows with `Stu.findAll()`.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: How do you handle the associations (associate) later then?